# Jquery: create pager(next - prev button) for new data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am using ajax to load more posts. For example.

I already have post like:

```
 <div class='post'>post1</div>
 <div class='post'>post2</div>
 <div class='post'>post3</div>
```

After press `Next Posts` button I receive new data:

```
 <div class='post'>post1</div>
 <div class='post'>post2</div>
 <div class='post'>post3</div>
 <div class='post'>post4</div>
 <div class='post'>post5</div>
 <div class='post'>post6</div>
```

But I only want new data appeared and the old data is hidden.

It means i can back old posts by `Prev Posts` Button. How can I use Jquery to do that?

Thank for your help.

Comment: Can you show us your jquery code and some more html? It should be something like `$(".post").remove();` before you filling in new data.

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia: I use like : `var c = a("<div></div>").append(c.replace(j, "")), c = c.find(i).children();           a(i).append(c); `

Answer (score 2):

Ex if you want to display 5 posts:

```
  //in you "nextButton" event handler
  var postLength = $('.post').length;
  $('.post')[postLength - 5].hide();
```

On your prevButton you will have to track where in the list you are, and show the posts as you cycle back through the list and then detect when you have reached the point where you load new things when you hit the nextButton.

Comment: +1 this covers just so many things I didn't even think of that now I feel ashamed of my little comment. Not deleting it (so no need to retrieve again later) and using an array like that. I'll save this answer for myself for later use (:

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia Glad I could help, it was an interesting little mind twister of a use case.  Please mark correct if it puts you on the path to your solution.

Comment: I'm not the OP, just a casual user stopping by to remark how useful your answer was.